# How to use Volley to pass String response obtained from JsonObject to textview in android

Tags: android, json, api, kotlin, android-volley

i am trying to design a horoscope app that takes zodiac sign as input and then shows daily prediction. whenever i run the app i always get error message saying "that didn't work" that i have specified. how do i pass the string value of the object "horoscope" into my textview button labelled as predictionView? i am a beginner
this is my code:

```
class Horoscope : AppCompatActivity() {
    companion object {
        const val SIGN_EXTRA = "sign_extra"
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_horoscope)
        val zodiacSign = intent.getStringExtra(SIGN_EXTRA)

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        val url = "http://horoscope-api.herokuapp.com/horoscope/today/$zodiacSign"

        val jsonObjectRequest = JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
            { response ->

                val prediction: String = response.getString("horoscope")

                predictionView.text = prediction
            }
        ) { _ -> predictionView.text = "That didn't work! Please enter valid Zodiac Sign." }

        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    }
}
```

this is what the link looks like:

```
{
  "date": "2021-07-07", 
  "horoscope": "You are a visionary and today you work towards building a successful future. But, expecting an instant result would be unfair. You need to have patience to bring in those dynamic changes in your life. Wait and watch, the patience would reap sweet fruits!", 
  "sunsign": "Scorpio"
}
```

Comment: Did you make sure you are getting the right `zodiacSign` from the intent?

Comment: check all objects, check value coming in response to see if "horoscope" is present in it.

Comment: @hopia yes i did, that seems to be working fine

Comment: @AlokGupta sorry i did not quite catch that, could u please elaborate? 
anyways I have updated the question and have included how the link looks like for a specific zodiac sign

Comment: Could you please provide the response of the URL when you hit through browser, basically looking at the API response we might get an idea of what the issue could be

Comment: As @AlokGupta suggested, it would be helpful to see the response. You could just have a print statement (`printStackTrace` works too).